# canvas.style.display = "block" not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I cannot explain why the first line in the below "buttonHandler" function will not work, the canvas is not displayed after this statement. Yet the first line of the "startPlay" function is the same and this displays the canvas! If anyone can see why from this section of code please let me know..

thanks.

I have tried this in Chrome and Firefox with the same results.

```
function buttonHandler(){
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    var menuDisplay = document.getElementById("menuDisplay");
    menuDisplay.style.display = "none";

    drawingSurface.font = readyDisplay.font;
    drawingSurface.fillStyle = readyDisplay.fillStyle;
    drawingSurface.textBaseline = readyDisplay.textBaseline;
    drawingSurface.fillText(readyDisplay.text, readyDisplay.x, readyDisplay.y);
    window.setTimeout("startPlay()", 3000);
}

function startPlay(){
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    gameOver.style.display = "none";
    balls=[];
    for(var i=0;i < sprites.length; i++){
        var thisSprite = sprites[i];
        if(thisSprite !== cup){
            removeObject(thisSprite, sprites);
        }
    }
    score = 0;
    totalSeconds = 5;
    gameState = PLAYING;
    drawingSurface.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000); // Start the countdown timer
    timeToBall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 50;
    update();
}
```

Comment: Need to full code to see. Jsfiddle is for us.

Comment: Never use `setTimeout`/`setInterval` with strings, because then they use the evil `eval`! Use a reference to a function instead (`setTimeout(tick, 1e3)`)

Comment: How do you know the canvas is not displayed?

Comment: I know the canvas is not displayed because when the menuDisplay.style.display = "none"; line is run only the body background is displayed for 3 seconds then the canvas comes back as the startPlay function runs.

Comment: canvas variable is not set anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot help you. Please post a self contained example. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve at what that means.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running your code within a `window.onload` event in the page.

When you call a `setTimeout` like this with a stringed function:

```
window.setTimeout("startPlay()", 3000); // just a string reference
```

the `startPlay()` will be evaluated on the *global* `window` object which means the scope won't have access to `startPlay()` at the time it will be evaluated as the function is a child of the function for the `onload` call and therefor inaccessible from `window` scope.

**[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/z5fKA/)** (nothing will happen but look at the code)

By changing `setTimeout()` to use a *function reference* this will work as the function is available at the time the reference is (child scopes has access to the inner workings of parent scopes but not vica versa).

Here the function reference itself will be transferred to the timeout event callback rather than a string reference:

```
window.setTimeout(startPlay, 3000); // now we have an actual function reference
```

This goes for the other instance as well (and this is also more secure).

**[Live working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/eM9Kj/)** (almost same code, just a direct function ref.)

Hope this helps!